# spring security handle exception throws from filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

i want to throw back filter exception to client but i am getting authentication exception with status code as 500

```
public Authentication validateToken(String token, HttpServletRequest req) throws TokenExpiredException {
    try {
        String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (validateToken(token, userDetails)) {
                logger.debug("valid token");
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthenticationToken(token,
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(), userDetails);
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(req));
                return authentication;
            }
        }
        return null;
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException jwtExp) {
        throw new TokenExpiredException("Session expired, please login again", Instant.now());
    } catch (TokenExpiredException tokExp) {
        throw tokExp;
    }
}
```

my security config is

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthFilter(userAuthenticationProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(customizer -> customizer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.requestMatchers("/api/v1/fmApp/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/admin/getRetailOutletForUser")
                        .hasAnyRole(USERROLE.ADMIN.name(), USERROLE.USER.name()).requestMatchers("/api/v1/admin/**")
                        .hasRole(USERROLE.ADMIN.name()).anyRequest().authenticated())
                .exceptionHandling(customizer -> customizer.authenticationEntryPoint(userAuthenticationEntryPoint));
        return http.build();
    }


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
    }
```

i need throw the "Session expired, please login again" when token get expired, but exceptionHandling is getting invoked and it is throwing authentication error. so how to throw custom exception and override spring security default exception behaviour

Comment: Are you handling exceptions globally? I think the link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-exceptionhandler may be helpful.

Comment: as per the latest spring version, documentaion says - "Allows configuring exception handling. This is automatically applied when using {@link EnableWebSecurity}"